# Тильда Webhook возвращает 405 ошибку

Tags: webhook, tilda

Работаю с тильда. Создал форму, которую пытаюсь привязать к Webhook. Кроме того создал на своем сервере адрес страницы возвращающей значение "Ok".

```
        header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');

        $headers = "From: from@webhookservesite.ru";

        $message = print_r($_POST,true);
        @mail('mymail@rambler.ru', 'Tilda TEST', $message, $headers);

        echo"ok";
```

Как настроить Webhook написано [тут](https://help-ru.tilda.cc/forms/webhook).

В настройках тильды устанавливаю метод POST и не знаю какие значения ввести для подчеркнутых значений: http://joxi.ru/8AnLDJjiKn08om . Откуда они берутся? Если отключаю POST-метод на Off коннект не проходит. Выдает ошибку 405. Текст ошибки:

> [405] Method not allowed: HTTP/1.1 405 Method Not Allowed Server: nginx/1.6.2 Date: Fri, 16 Jun 2023 08:10:07 GMT Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8 Transfer-Encoding: chunked Connection: keep-alive allow: GET, HEAD Cache-Control: no-cache, private pragma: no-cache expires: -1 pre.sf-dump { display: none !important; } The POST method is not supported for route tilda. Supported methods: GET, HEAD.

Answer (score 0):

Можно ввести любые значения, например API NAME: **TLD_API_KEY** и API KEY: **MgUxBoIwiFBkTxb**

И в своем скрипте проверяете

```
if ($_POST['TLD_API_KEY'] == 'MgUxBoIwiFBkTxb') {
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
    $headers = "From: from@webhookservesite.ru";
    $message = print_r($_POST,true);
    @mail('mymail@rambler.ru', 'Tilda TEST', $message, $headers);
    echo "ok";
}
```